# Flash movie rendering on top of dhtml menu

Tags: css, flash, dhtml, menu

How should one go about placing a flash movie beneath a dhtml menu?

On the following page: http://bit.ly/aZai8 , the flash movie appears on top of the dhtml drop down menus in Internet Explorer. This does not seem to be an issue in more civilized browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

inside the flash object tag and add the wmode="transparent" attribute to the embed tag inside it.

Answer (score 1):

In the embed code, set the wmode to transparent.

http://www.flashvista.com/details/item/1471/

Answer (score -1):

and add z-index to menu and swf object :)

Comment: z-index does not work for embedded windows like flash, it always will float on top of the viewport. wmode on the object  needs to be set to opaque or transparent in order for it to be embedded truly inline.

Comment: You are wrong. If you set wmode to transparent or opaque you can change its layer index by setting z-index value. You can chose a swf object that will be on top (if many swf-s) or object/layer. I used this method in 3 commercial projects.